# Kubernetes sevice with CluserIp does not pass the request to some of it's Endpoints

Tags: http, kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes. I have setup 3 node cluster with two workers according to [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-kubeadm-on-ubuntu-18-04).
My configurations

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.0", GitCommit:"641856db18352033a0d96dbc99153fa3b27298e5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T15:53:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.10", GitCommit:"575467a0eaf3ca1f20eb86215b3bde40a5ae617a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-11T12:32:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
 kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.0", GitCommit:"641856db18352033a0d96dbc99153fa3b27298e5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T15:51:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Deployed simple python service listen to 8000 port http and reply "Hello world"

my deployment config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-app
  labels:
    app: frontend-app
spec:
  replicas: 2 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pyfrontend
        image: rushantha/pyfront:1.0 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

Exposed this as a service
`kubectl expose deploy frontend-app --port 8000`

I can see it deployed and running.

```
kubectl describe svc frontend-app
Name:              frontend-app
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=frontend-app
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=frontend-app
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.113.192
Port:              <unset>  8000/TCP
TargetPort:        8000/TCP
Endpoints:         172.16.1.10:8000,172.16.2.9:8000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

when I log in to each service machine and do curl pods respond
ie. `curl 172.16.1.10:8000 or curl 172.16.2.9:8000`

However when I try to access the pods via the ClusterIp only one pod always responds. So curl sometimes hangs, most probably the other pod does not respond. I confirmed when I tail the access logs for both pods. One pod never received any requests.

```
curl 10.96.113.192:8000/ ---> Hangs sometimes.
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this and fix ?

Comment: Does you `--pod-network-cidr` matches subnet configured in flannel?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. pod-network-cidr did not match my flannel configuration. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Great news! I will place an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing the tutorial document and the outputs configuration
I discovered that the `--pod-network-cidr` declared in the document is different from the OP endpoints which solved the problem.

The network in the flannel configuration should match the `pod network CIDR` otherwise pods won`t be able to communicate with each other.

Some additional information that are worth checking:

1. Under the `CIDR Notation` [section](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-ip-addresses-subnets-and-cidr-notation-for-networking) there is a good explanation how this system works.
2. I find [this document](https://itnext.io/an-illustrated-guide-to-kubernetes-networking-part-1-d1ede3322727) about networking in kuberenetes very helpful.